# Why does my form reload the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I prefer submitting form values with AJAX by hitting "Return" and all my setups, which I did before, are working, but today it stopped working. Here are the the steps, which I have been following for a quite a long time.

1. Include jQuery
2. Setup my form
3. Preventing it form submitting

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('keyup', myFormSelector, function(event){
    if ( event.keyCode === 13 ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you change jQuery versions?

Comment: change the event to keydown

Comment: is `myFormSelector` somewhere in the same scope?

Comment: Code does not magically stop working. What changed?

Comment: Currently version 1.10.2

Comment: Did they stop working everywhere, or just in 1 implementation ? Also in all browsers, or just IE11 for example ? (did you just update your browser?)

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 2):

change the event to keydown and it will work.

Comment: keydown works, but why does it not work with 'keyup' anymore?

Comment: As you press the enter key two events are fired. First is keydown and the second is keyup. But before firing the keyup function the browser submits the form.

Answer (score 1):

try to disable the default behaviour from the submit event and add a SUBMIT-element (display:none).

If a form does have a submit-element, the return key does work like you want it.

Howto disable the submit event:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // disabling default submit with reload.
    // ajax code here
});
```

if this does not work, u may try this also:

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return false"> ... </form>
```

Returning false does stop submitting too.

When using submit elements instead of keyup/keydown, you will be able to add multiple forms on your page with the desired behaviour.

Comment: Hehe, it's simply the way HTML was originally meant to be :D